# Negative adjusted R-squared of fixed effect plm function

Tags: r, fixed, effect, plm

I am currently writing my thesis and when I use the `plm` (from package `plm`) function (pooled, within or random) I get a very low R-squared and negative adjusted R-squared. However, when I run the `lm()` function with dummy variables, the adjusted R-squared is around 0.4. What am I doing wrong?

This is the first three rows of my data:

```
   structure(list(table.id = c("alameda, ca, 2003", "alameda, ca, 2004", 
"alameda, ca, 2005"), location = c("Alameda, CA", "Alameda, CA", 
"Alameda, CA"), year = c(2003, 2004, 2005), search.fund = c(0, 
0, 0), search.fund.binary = c(0, 0, 0), time.avg = c(0, 0, 0), 
    distance.avg = c(0, 0, 0), avg.income.capita = c(40266, 41973, 
    43594), real.gdp = c(86355025, 88443534, 90705419), unemployment = c(6.8, 
    5.9, 5.1), education.rate = c(34.9, 34.9, 34.9), urban.id = c(1, 
    1, 1), no.establishments = c(46548.75, 46623.5, 46254.25), 
    no.building.permit = c(14828, 15239, 14883), population.size = c(1454163, 
    1445721, 1441545), no.establishments.capita = c(0.0320106824338124, 
    0.0322493067472908, 0.0320865807172166), no.building.permit.capita = c(0.0101969311555857, 
    0.0105407613225512, 0.0103243395107333)), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is my `lm` model:

```
sf.lm.fe.nb <- lm(search.fund ~ education.rate + unemployment + 
    urban.id + no.establishments.capita + no.building.permit.capita + 
    factor(location) + factor(year), data = df)  
summary(sf.lm.fe.nb)
```

and this is my `plm` model:

```
sf.plm.fe.nb  <- plm(search.fund ~ education.rate + unemployment + 
   urban.id + no.establishments.capita + no.building.permit.capita,
   data = df, model = "within", effect = "twoways", 
   index = c("location", "year"))

summary(sf.plm.fe.nb)
```

Both use the same data sets

Comment: Questions to the SO [tag:r] tag should include complete reproducible examples.  See instructions at the top of that page.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added them

Comment: No one but you can run that because only you have df. Please read the link again.

Comment: I hope this helps now :) I am not lazy, but I am doing this for the first time and I am not really experienced with programming. I am sorry, if this offended you.

Comment: Unfortunately objects that contain internal pointers are not reproducible even if you use  `dput` so you will need to convert your data.table to a data frame and then `dput` that.  Also all code lines should be indented by 4 spaces in which case SO will format them for you.

Comment: "when I run lm function with dummy variables" is not the case in your question. You actually used the predictors for running lm() . You get a negative r^2 because the final model is not much better than an intercept only model.. Chances are you over specified some terms

Comment: If the code is fine, I would vote to migrate this to SO as it has more to do with statistics (i.e how to use a plm correctly) than programming

Comment: If you strip out the class item for data.table and the internal.pointer it becomes a valid data.frame expression.

Comment: Changed to a data frame and then dput-ed. Can you use it now? (I feel like a three-year-old kid :/)